# Echo next week correctly

Tags: php, date

Im having a scheduele that I want to view this week, next week and two weeks forward.

My problem is now when it's a new year incoming, and my code doesnt work at all.

I have used code like this:

```
<?php echo date('W'); ?> and <?php echo date('W')+1; ?>
```

I have then used +2 and +3 for echo next 2 weeks.

This is not working now when current week is 51, because next week is 52 but the week after that echos as 53, and I want to find the right way to solve this.

So how to you guys do this?

Comment: try something like `$startOfWeek = strtotime('-'.date('w').' days');
echo date('Y-m-d', $startOfWeek);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$date = "2012-12-03";
$date = strtotime($date);
$date = strtotime("+7 day", $date);
echo date('Y-m-d', $date);
```

It will work

For your case it will work. It will give you next monday

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next monday'));
```

**Edited**. to get week:

```
$date = "2012-12-03";
$date = strtotime($date);
$date = strtotime("+7 day", $date);
$week = (int)date('W', $date); 
echo $week;
```

Comment: But that doesn't echo the next week, right? I just want next week in wekknumber.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+1 week"));
```